# How can i send two different variable in one props with v-if in Vue-JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm trying to send diferent datas to my other component.
Basically, when my variable `firstvalue` is not null,  i want to send `firstvalue`.

And it's working, but now i want to send `secondvalue` if the `secondvalue` is not null.
Basically right now i have this

```
<props-form
  v-if="firstvalue !== null"
    :point="firstvalue"
    :eventBus="eventBus"
    @cancel="() => cancelFct()"
></props-form>
```

And i would like to do something like this :

```
<props-form
  v-if="firstvalue !== null"
    :point="firstvalue"
  v-if="secondvalue !== null"
    :point="secondvalue"
    :eventBus="eventBus"
    @cancel="() => cancelFct()"
></props-form>
```

But it's not working because i can't "duplicate" props and because i can't put two v-if like this.

How can i do something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<props-form
  v-if="firstvalue !== null || secondvalue !== null"
    :point="firstvalue || secondvalue"
    :eventBus="eventBus"
    @cancel="() => cancelFct()"
></props-form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would like `firstvalue` to have higher priority than `secondvalue` of being passed down to `props-form` as the `point` prop. I recommend that you use a computed property for this scenario.

```html
<props-form v-if="point !== null" :point="point" />
```

```js
computed: {
  point() {
    return this.firstvalue || this.secondvalue
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that if `point === undefined`, the component will still render. So I assume you only want it not to render if `point === null`